# Javascript onkeypress delete or dot

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

Is there any way to find out if the user pressed the delete key or dot? It has the same keycode in FireFox.

Comment: Has that something to do this the numeric pad on keyboards (wenn NUM-LOCK is off)? There is a similar question regarding C# here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206608/how-do-i-detect-a-numberdecimalseparator-in-a-keydown-event-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Detecting keystrokes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html), it is possible, provided that:

- you search for the keyCode (**8** for delete) onkeydown/up, and
- ignore both onkeypress and charCode (Especially if you consider the fact that IE does not fire keypressed event, only key up/down).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a nice overview regarding browser behavior when it comes to keyboard events:

[JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) *(it's quite recent, too: July 7, 2008)*

Scroll down to to "3.2. Values Returned on Character Events", there is a table showing what different browsers do.

Bottom line is: It depends.